# Does JSF flash keepMessages property persist?

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF problem that I think can be solved by adding a call to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);`.  However, I'm not clear on some of the implications.  Will the `keepMessages` property remain `true` across the application?

This is a mature application, so I'm concerned that setting this property will cause a bunch of messages to suddenly start popping up.  If it does persist, is there any way I can set this property for the next redirect only?  Or do I need to manually switch it back to `false` somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Will the keepMessages property remain true across the application?*

No, it applies to the current "flash session" only. I.e. just the current HTTP request. It's cleared out in the next request in the same session.

See also the [class' javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html):

> The Flash concept is taken from Ruby on Rails and provides a way to pass temporary objects between the user views generated by the faces lifecycle. As in Rails, **anything one places in the flash will be exposed to the next view encountered by the same user session and then cleared out**.

And the [method's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#setKeepMessages%28boolean%29):

> ### setKeepMessages
>
> ...
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> `newValue` - the new value for this property on this session

Noted should be, however, that Mojarra had several serious issues related to the flash scope. E.g. the message wouldn't appear when you navigate to a different path. Or the message would re-appear in a different window when you happen to navigate to the same path. That kind of things. All of those issues are however already fixed since Mojarra 2.1.18. There's only a security exploit left, see also [issue 2126](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2126), found and reported by my fellow Arjan Tijms. As long as you don't put sensitive information in flash messages like credit card numbers or so, this is harmless.

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for.  Thank you!